# Apache Drill UI server binding issue

Tags: apache-drill

I am trying to configure Apache drill.
I have downloaded, build and tested few things already, clustered configured on Zookeeper seems to run fine.
I am okay with the drill bit startup and all but the inbuilt Jetty server used by Drill is not binding to all the ips automatically.

Output of netstat:

```
$>sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8047
tcp6       0      0 :::8047                 :::*                    LISTEN      23041/java
```

I want to make it listen from 0.0.0.0.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delving into it a bit, I see in the source code, drill uses Jetty Server class for the UI, that class has a convenience constructor that only accepts a port.
http://api.dpml.net/org/mortbay/jetty/6.1.0/org/mortbay/jetty/Server.html

Looks like it would require using the .addConnector() to support port and IP address.